# BINDINGSGENERATOR: warning : matched no nodes

Tags: android, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android

I created a Android Java Bindings project, added the jar file ([Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)) to the Jars folder.

The warning I received is:

`BINDINGSGENERATOR:  warning BG8A00: <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.loopj.android.http']/class[@name='BinaryHttpResponseHandler']/method[@name='OnFailure']"/> matched no nodes`

My `Transforms/Metadata.xml` is as follows:

```
<metadata>

    <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.loopj.android.http']" name="managedName">AsyncHttp</attr>
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.loopj.android.http']/class[@name='BinaryHttpResponseHandler']/method[@name='OnFailure']" />

</metadata>
```

What am I missing?